# Determinig subgroup of particular order by class equation of a group.

Tags: group-theory

A  group, whose class equation is 1+4+5+5+5, contains a subgroup of order 10. 
true or false?

I know about sylow theorems, conjugacy classes, class equation but don't know about this statement.

Comment: So, how many elements of order $5$ are there? How many Sylow-5-subgroups?

Comment: It might be less distracting to prove that every group of order $20$ has a subgroup of order $10$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician there is only one Sylow-5-subgroup in this group. This subgroup should be cyclic so it has 4 elements of order 5.

Comment: @DerekHolt how can I prove this that every group of order 20 has a subgroup of order 10?

Comment: Use Sylow's theorem to prove that there is a normal Sylow 5-subgroup $P$  and then take the inverse image in $G$ of a subgroup of order $2$ in $G/P$.

Comment: @DerekHolt sylow 5-subgroup is normal in G. So factor group G/P is a subgroup of order 4 which has a subgroup of order 2. So there is a subgroup of order 2 in G. I didn't understand the inverse part.